# ошибка в методе scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy

День добрый.
Возникла проблема при попытке найти минимум функции:

```
def sr_0(w_0, w_1):
    a = sum([(data['Height'][n] - (int(w_0) + float(w_1)*data['Weight'][n]))**2 for n in range(1, 25000)])
    return a

from scipy.optimize import minimize
x = (0, 0)
bnds = ((-100, 100), (-5, 5))

res = minimize(sr_0, x,  method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds)
```

выдает ошибку *sr_0() missing 1 required positional argument: 'w_1'* 
не могу  понять в чем дело, ведь я передаю 2 аргумента, переменной *x*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете все-таки одну переменную с `tuple`

Попробуйте в функцию одним параметром передавать, например:

```
def sr_0(w):
    w_0, w_1 = w

    a = sum([(data['Height'][n] - (int(w_0) + float(w_1)*data['Weight'][n]))**2 for n in range(1, 25000)])
    return a
```

Comment: спасибо, прошло без ошибки, хотя выдал явно не оптимальный результат

Comment: Все отлично, int заменил на float и стало супер гуд

Comment: @Denladon, круто :) тогда примите ответ как правильный (галочка слева от ответа) и поставьте что ответ полезен (стрелочка вверх) ;)